# How to change linked issue number with commit message

Tags: git, github

I would like to change linked issue number with git commit message.

Example:

- Suppose there is 2 issue: 12, 25
- In several git commit message I have used as like as follows (These commits are pushed too) :

```
commit message 1 #25
commit message 2 #25
```

- But it should be linked with issue `12`

Is there any way to change now the linked issue number from `25` to `12`?

Comment: Well... you need to adjust the commit message... which is done with a `git commit --amend` if you are on the revision or with `git rebase -i` specifying `reword` as the action for the revision. Have you tried that?

Comment: have not tried yet. Will the above mentioned command keep the old commit or it will rewritten them? Eg: I will not see anymore `commit message 1 #25` as it will be converted to `commit message 1 #12`. Or both commit message will be existed?

Comment: No part of any commit can ever be changed, so Git doesn't even try to do *that*. Instead, Git makes a *new and different commit* with the updated message. This necessitates copying any later commits as well, which means you are doing what people call "rewriting history". This isn't inherently *bad*, it's just a thing to know you're doing. The original commits remain, but if you update a GitHub pull request using the new commits instead, GitHub know what to do with that.

Comment: Note that you must update the GitHub side of all of this *before* you get the PR merged in, so that when GitHub do the merge work, they use the updated (replacement) commits instead of the original (bad) ones and thus update and/or close the correct issue number.

Comment: This all assumes *GitHub*. I added the [tag:github] tag here. If you're using some other hosting system, much of this may be different.